# Sort and filter data in GridView Yii2 where column is not in database

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

If I have 2 fields in db - probability and influence and I need a column in GridView where these two fields are multiplied. I managed to add it there like:

```
    [
            'attribute' => 'priority',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return $model->influence * $model->probability;
            },
        ],
```

But can't handle the sorting, because that column is not in db and adding filters to $query causes only errors.

```
    $query = Risks::find();
    $query->select(`probability*influence AS priority`);
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
```

**Updated (works Asc and Desc but not with filters)**

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Risks::find();

    $query->joinWith(['author', 'proj']);

    $query->select('*, (probability * influence) as priority');

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $dataProvider->setSort([
        'attributes' => [
           // 'id',
            'probability',
            'risks',
            'influence',
            'del' => [
                'asc' => ['risks.del' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['risks.del' => SORT_DESC],
            ],
            'priority' => [
                'asc' => ['priority' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['priority' => SORT_DESC],
                'label' => 'Priority',
            ],
            'proj' => [
                'asc' => ['projects.name' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['projects.name' => SORT_DESC],
            ],
            'author' => [
                'asc' => ['users.name' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['users.name' => SORT_DESC],
            ]
        ]
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }


    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'proj_id' => $this->proj_id,
        'author_id' => $this->author_id,
        'influence' => $this->influence,
        'probability' => $this->probability,
        //'del' => $this->del,
    ])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'projects.name', $this->proj])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'users.name', $this->author]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'risks', $this->risks]);

    $query->having('priority = '. $this->priority);
    //$query->having(['priority' => $this->priority]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**STEP 1: Add a getter function to your base `Risks` model:**

```
public function getPriority() {
    return ($this->probability * $this->influence);
}
```

**STEP 2: Add an attribute `priority` to your model `RisksSearch` and configure your rules.**

```
/* your calculated attribute */
public $priority;

/* setup rules */
public function rules() {
   return [
       /* your other rules */
       [['priority'], 'safe']
   ];
}
```

**STEP 3: Edit the search() method to include the calculated field `priority`**

```
public function search($params) {

    $query = Person::find();

    $query->select('*, (probability * influence) as priority');

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    /**
     * Setup your sorting attributes
     * Note: This is setup before $this->load($params)
     */
    $dataProvider->setSort([
        'attributes' => [
            'id',
            'priority' => [
                'asc' => ['priority' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['priority' => SORT_DESC],
                'label' => 'Priority',
                'default' => SORT_ASC
            ],
        ]
    ]);
    ...
```

**STEP 4: Add `$query->andFilterWhere()` after `$this->load($params)` to be able to filter the calculated field**

```
// use the operator you wish, i.e. '=', '>', '<' etc
$query->andFilterWhere(['=', '(probability * influence)', $this->priority]);
```

Comment: Jap, thanks, now I can sort `asc` and `desc`! :) But how can I filter? Tried `$query->select('*, (probability * influence) as priority')->andFilterWhere(['priority'=>$this->priority]);` after `$this->load($params);` but got `column "priority" does not exist` :(

Comment: Tried, but got `SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: ...s" ON "risks"."proj_id" = "projects"."id" HAVING priority = 
`
Tried `$query->having(['priority' => $this->priority]);` but then `column "priority" does not exist`

Comment: could you maybe paste the whole query here?

Comment: Added all search function in question

Comment: Well done on solving the problem! Updated my question to show the sollution for future readers.

Comment: Nicely explained, but the fact that the exact same formula (probability*influene) has to appear in **3**!! separate places makes me cringe hard. :/

Comment: This is the only answer to this problem in the whole internet, which really describes how to sort by calculated columns in Yii2. I could easily use this to add subqueries using `$query->select[] = ...` by which one could sort.

Answer (score 3):

Removed

```
      $query->select('*, (probability * influence) as priority');
```

changed

```
          'priority' => [
                'asc' => ['(probability * influence)' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['(probability * influence)' => SORT_DESC],
                'label' => 'Priority',
              ],
```

and after $this->load($params);

```
          $query->andFilterWhere(['=', '(probability * influence)', $this->priority]);
```

And search works as needed! :)

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, which works for sorting non-table field

```
     $dataProvider->sort->attributes['customer'] = [
        'asc' => ['customer' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['customer' => SORT_DESC],
    ];
```