# Yii2. How to use aggregation in MongoDB/ActiveQuery?

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2

How to build aggregation in MongoDB/ActiveQuery? For example, if use MySQL/ActiveQuery my query looks like this:

```
$query = new Query();
$query->select(['name', '(field1 + field2) AS calculated_field']);
```

How to build this query in MongoDB/ActiveQuery?

(I'm using query for ActiveDataProvider. I need not only for display field, need for sort by this field too)

Answer (score 0):

You can use properties in Yii2 (getters and setters) for Model, so that you don't have to hardcode it in sql query.
For instance, you have some model "Human" with two columns: name, surname.
And by writing

```
$human = Human::findOne(0);
echo $human->fullname;
```

You want to aggregate $human->name and $human->surname. So then you can do the following in Model code

```
 * @property string $name (from database)
 * @property string $surname (from database)
 * @property string $fullname
class Human extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
...
public function getFullname() {
        return $this->name.' '.$this->surname;
    }
...
}
```

That's all, when you call $human->fullname, it will return the getFullname() function value

Comment: I need not only for display field, need for sort by this field too.

Comment: @АндрейЛитвиненко, then you can simply repeat the given steps for custom activerecord column http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28578057/sort-and-filter-data-in-gridview-yii2-where-column-is-not-in-database

Comment: thanks. This example works only for MySql but doesn't work with MongDb

Answer (score 0):

In your view, just add:

```
$collection = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('collection1');
$join = $collection->aggregate([[
                '$lookup' => [
                    'from'         => 'collection2',
                    'localField'   => 'same_field',
                    'foreignField' => 'same_field',
                    'as' => 'collection1'
                    ]
                ]]);
```